# Issue in getting the argument's options (contains space) list in Linux with optarg

Tags: c++, linux

(C++ [cmake] and Linux CentOS 7.0)

I have a command with an argument in Linux whose option is a list of space-separated values:

The command generally looks like this:

```
getemail -c robert 12345 google.com
```

My argument's option is:

```
robert 12345 google.com
```

I pass it to a variable like this:

```
char* option_value = optarg;
```

But neither option_value nor `optarg` contain the full options sequence, they only contain the sequence of chars preceding the very first space, hence when I `cout << optarg;` I get:

```
robert
```

But when I debug it, I see `optarg` contains the full list of chars separated by `\000`, an array like this:

```
r
o
b
e
r
t
/000
1
2
3
4
5
/000
g
o
o
g
l
e
.
c
o
m
```

Can anyone please tell me what's the issue?

Comment: `optarg` will only contain useful information if the argument at issue follows an option specified as taking an argument in the argument list. (e.g. `int o; while ((o = getopt (argc, argv, "c:") != -1)` will provide a pointer to `robert`when `o = c`, because option `c` was specified as having an argument `c:` in the argument list). You must copy `optarg` to `option_value` in C)

Comment: I need a more detailed explanation, thanks

Comment: Generally you process your option with a switch statement, e.g. `int o; while ((o = getopt (argc, argv, "abc:") != -1) { switch (o) { case 'a' : //handle a; break; case 'b' : //handle b; break; case 'c' : if (optarg) strcpy (option_value, optarg); //finish handling c; break } }`. 2 things: (1) `optarg` only points to the string `robert` when `o=c` in the case statement, and (2) then only because the option `c` in the option-list (`"abc:"`)is followed by a `:` telling getopt that `c` has a mandatory option that follows.

Comment: OH! if you want to pass `robert 12345 google.com` as a single object and have it available as `optarg` to some option, then `double-quote` it (e.g. `"robert 12345 google.com"`) and it will be contained in `optarg` following the option you specify with a `':'`.

Comment: Thanks very much Rankin

Comment: Sure, it takes a little while to get your head around `getopt`, but thankfully there are many good examples. Even the `man getopt` pages provides a decent one and there are many here and on the web. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass the robert 12345 google.com as a single object and have it available as optarg to some option. You can use double quote or single quote in the command line argument.

Don't forget to give the ':' for option in getopt.